# Restart Windows services during shutdown

Tags: windows-10

The internet says: `with Fast Startup enabled, Windows closes all applications and logs off all users, just as in a normal cold shutdown`. I experience a bit differently. I run application servers like Adobe Coldfusion and shut the PC down. After a new start idle process has plenty hours of CPU time used according to task manager. Coldfusion once in while informs me database connections pooled for reuse are broken. When I manually stop the Coldfusion service before shutdown it's not up after restart.

I now wonder if I can do something to make sure all services are cleanly stopped on shutdown and restarted when I freshly start the PC.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what is your reference when you state that *"The Internet says"*?  Personally, I am not a big fan of Fast Startup when it comes to mission-essential Windows machines.  Our team normally disables it on each Windows 10 computer to ensure that everything stops (and restarts) gracefully.

Comment: A phrasal search for that quote is a How To Geek article. The rest of the context makes it clear that the computer logs everyone out and then "hibernates." So I presume the quoted sentence refers to user-mode applications. Server applications and services are often running prior to logon.

Comment: @Run5k It's not a mission critical machine. Looking for experience.

Comment: Understood.  Essentially, the answer posted by IronWilliamCash recommends exactly what I was thinking.  In your shoes, I would go with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast shutdown/startup is not a real shutdown. It's more of a hybrid between a shutdown and a hibernate. This means many operations are not done both at startup and shutdown. This also means that Windows resumes the state you were in as best as it can, so it will not restart services that were stopped manually pre-shutdown.

In your case it's possible that the ColdFusion server does not work well with hibernation methods. I recommend you simply disable the fast startup/shutdown for your this machine. To do so you can simply go the the power options in Windows and disable it in the shutdown settings of your power plan.

Comment: I believe this is the best answer but an alernative is to write a script that restarts the service(s) in question.  Of course its sort of strange to hibernate a computer running server services, normally a server, is either available because its up or its not available because its turned off or the services are not running because of manual intervention..

Comment: @Ramhound It's a development machine. To some extent it's managed by company's administrator. They enabled fast startup.

Comment: Please keep in mind that `Fast Startup` is actually enabled in a default Windows 10 installation.  Is it possible that your Sys Admin team simply didn't modify the default Windows 10 configuration in that regard, and that you could ask them do disable `Fast Startup` based upon the negative effects you have encountered?